# Using command line parameters to manipulate values in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given a variety of .csv files and for each one I need to identify the keys associated with the longest list; and print that key. As well as the values that only appear in the last column of the csv file, and print that value. I am encouraged to use command line parameters, which I am new to so I'm having a hard time with this. Here is an example of a csv file given:
Grasshopper,Grass
Lizard,Grasshopper
Hawk,Grasshopper,Lizard,Rabbit,Mouse,Snake
Rabbit,Grass
Snake,Mouse
Mouse,Grass

So the key with the longest list I would be trying to print is the Hawk.
This is the code I have so far:

```
    import sys
    import csv
    if len(sys.argv) != "":
        inf = open(sys.argv[0], "r")
        outf = open(sys.argv[1], "w")

        words = 0
        maxvalue = 0

        line = inf.readline()
        for line in data:
            while line != "":
               words = words + len(line.split())

               maxvalue = maxvalue + words
               if words > value:
                   maxline = words

              # Read the next line from the file.
              line = inf.readline()

       outf.write(str(maxvalue))
```

But with my little knowledge of command line parameters it doesn't work as I am given an index error, and I'm unsure of how to fix it.
Prior to this code I have opened/read the files. I'm using **python3**, any help would be much appreciated!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `if` condition to:

```
if sys.argv[1:]:
```

`[1:]` means 'every element from `sys.argv` except the first'. `sys.argv[1:]` will be an empty list if there are no commandline arguments, which evaluates as `False`. A non-empty list evaluates as `True`.

The first element of `sys.argv` is the file name (or `''` if you're in the REPL) so

```
if sys.argv:
```

will always evaluate as `True`.

**Try this in the REPL**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['']
>>> bool(sys.argv)
True
>>> sys.argv[1:]
[]
>>> bool(sys.argv[1:])
False
>>> if sys.argv:
...     print('aaa')
...
aaa
>>> if sys.argv[1:]:
...     print('aaa')
...
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work in terms of getting rid of the error message. I'm not sure what I would call on to print? also, is the outf write function necessary? or is It possible to get the correct input by just including a read statement? Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you. Given the solution worked, you should mark my answer as 'accepted'.

To print I would use the builtin `print` function. It prints to the stdout stream, meaning the text will come up in your terminal.

Regarding `inf` and `outf`: If you want to write to a file, yes you need the `outf.write`. But you should access files using the `with` statement, this is safer because you don't need to remember to close the file (which you have forgotten to do):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `if` condition to:

```
if sys.argv:
```